# How should we prioritise conversion of website pages to be converted to pwa?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

We have an e-commerce website with several pages like: product search page, product details page, offers page, blogs.

We are planning migration to PWA. How should we prioritise it:

1. Should we pick pages with returning users first i.e. product details page, offers page etc.?
2. OR pick high traffic & most critical pages i.e. product search page first?
3. Pages with lots of images, videos like blogs, news first?

What kind of pages are best suitable for PWA?

Answer (score 0):

I use Polymer for most of the PWA sites which use app shell model so it is easier for me to use enable PWA.

I assume you are not using any framework and you don't have app shell.

Homepage is the most important page. My recommendation is enable PWA for homepage first.

Then go by monitoring traffic statistics.

I think user directly don't land in product search result page, you can skip that for now.

Best possible way will be making the homepage pwa and then go by the navigation links from homepage. Don't just make one page pwa without homepage. User may click on homepage link and feel lost.

Most of the time it depends on your application and visitors.

Why don't make all the pages PWA? It is now very easy. Take a look at [WorkboxJs](https://workboxjs.org/) to generate service worker.